Special Characters in Column Names while saving a Delta Format file via PySpark
Getting the error while trying to write a delta format file via Azure Databrics to ADLS
AnalysisException: Found invalid character(s) among ' ,;{}()\n\t=' in the column names of your schema. Please use other characters and try again.
I have semicolon(:) and period(.) in my column names but it's important that I keep these characters in the names, hence I have to save the file with same column names. I tried saving the CSV and it's fine but delta is causing the above error.
I am using the following command:
sourcedf.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").option("mergeSchema", "true").option("spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.columnMapping.mode", "name").format("delta").save(path)
even tried this option
option("delta.columnMapping.mode", "name")

Could you please provide your sample delta table?

Maybe use backticks? See PySpark - Special characters in column names

@niko already inside backticks.

You need to remove the special characters from column names. You may add this line before writing the dataframe :
import re

sourcedf2 = sourcedf.select(*[f.col(c).alias(re.sub("\W+", "", c)) for c in sourcedf.columns])


The whole point is to keep the column names as they are, but thanks.
